# How to find the Swift translation of an Obj-C enum

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have an enum defined in Obj-C:

```
typedef enum {
    VUObjectSyncStatusSynced = 0,
    VUObjectSyncStatusCreated,
    VUObjectSyncStatusDeleted,
} VUObjectSyncStatus;
```

I try to use one of the values in Swift - `.Created` - but get the error:

```
 Type 'VUObjectSyncStatus' has no member 'Created'
```

Which it should, but whatever. I'll just use what it is translated as. However, code completion doesn't give me any options.

So two parts - specifically, what would the Swift version of `VUObjectSyncStatusCreated` be? Second, how can I find this out in future cases if code completion doesn't work?

Comment: Declare the Obj-C enum as `NS_ENUM` and it will work correctly.

Comment: @Sulthan Is there a way to work with the enum as is?

Comment: @Sulthan Got it - if I just use `VUObjectSyncStatusCreated` as is it works in Swift

Answer (score 3):

Declare your enum like this and it should work

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, VUObjectSyncStatus) {
    VUObjectSyncStatusSynced,
    VUObjectSyncStatusCreated,
    VUObjectSyncStatusDeleted
};
```

Let me know.